# Decision Tree for Heap-Sort with 3 elements {a1,a2,a3}

Tags: data-structures

I am trying to draw a decision tree for HEAP-SORT for 3 elements {a1,a2,a3}
any suggestions, I did not find anything on the web.

Comment: It's not clear exactly where you are having trouble.

Comment: I don't know how to draw this tree, its not like merge sort.

Comment: Are you asking how, given an arbitrary array of 3 elements, you rearrange it into a valid binary heap?